# D3 - SVG elements being positioned from body, not SVG container

Tags: d3.js, svg

I am trying to us d3 inside of rails app.

There are other elements that are not part of the visualization taking space at the top and left of the page.

My problem is when I do positioning (x, y) to any svg element, it seems to be doing it based on the `body` of the page, not the svg. Is this typical? Is there a way I can always position from the (0,0) position of an svg, the top left corner ?

I am selecting an element, appending an `svg` and `g` tag then a `text` I guess I was expecting because everything was being appended it would be placed with/positioned in it's parent.

Example:

```
var g = d3.select("#chart-area").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
```

```
g.append("text")
  .attr("class", "x axis-label")
  .attr("x", width / 2)
  .attr("y", height + 75)
  .attr("font-size", "20px")
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .text("Months")
```

The result of this is that the label will show up underneath the UI of the gem.

This is not the actual project, its a tutorial, but I am using basically the same code:
https://jsfiddle.net/r6jkht9v/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was mostly based around adding some bootstrap tags.

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          d3
        </div>
</div>
```

After adding this svg elements I appended stayed with in the svg.